# Why am I getting a null pointer for my hashcode?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

I am trying to create my own hashcode, but I am getting a null pointer error for it. Is it because my objects, Suit and Face, do not have either own hashcodes?I've been looking up examples of hashcodes online, since this is my first time using them, and I tried incorporating from the examples that I saw online.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

enum Suit {Diamonds, Hearts, Spades, Clubs};
enum Face {
            King, Queen, Jack, Ten, Nine, Eight, Seven,
            Six, Five, Four, Three, Two, Ace, Joker
        };

public class SuitAndFace {

    Suit suit;
    Face face;

    SuitAndFace(Suit s, Face f){
        suit = s;
        face = f;
    }

    public String toString(){
        if(!face.toString().equals("Joker"))
            return face + " of " + suit;
        else//joker has no suit
            return face.toString();
    }

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){

    System.out.println(" in equals");
    if(o instanceof SuitAndFace){
        SuitAndFace s = (SuitAndFace) o; 
        if(this.face.equals(s.face) && this.suit.equals(s.face))
            return true;    
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 7 * hash + this.suit.hashCode();
    hash = 7 * hash + this.face.hashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

}

UPDATED METHODS:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){

    System.out.println(" in equals");
    if(o instanceof SuitAndFace){
        SuitAndFace s = (SuitAndFace) o; 
        if(face != null && suit != null && this.face.equals(s.face) && this.suit.equals(s.face))
            return true;    
    }
    System.out.println("no match!");
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    if(suit != null && face != null){
        hash = 7 * hash + this.suit.hashCode();
        hash = 7 * hash + this.face.hashCode();
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: `suit` must be `null`. We need to see where you use the constructor.

Comment: I'mguessing suit or face may be null causing the null pointer. Inherently all objects have a .hasCode ()

Comment: @PaulBoddington   here is how I use my contructor/object hashMap.get(new SuitAndFace(findSuit(suitBox.getSelectedItem().toString()), findFace(faceBox.getSelectedItem().toString())))    this pretty much just creates the values from an existing source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just realised that you seem to be representing jokers as `suit == null`, `face == Joker`. You'll get a `NullPointerException` whenever you do `suit.anything` if the card is a joker.

That line could be:

```
hash = 7 * hash + this.suit == null ? 0 : this.suit.hashCode();
```

Alternatively you could add a `Joker` constant to the `Suit` enum too and then you wouldn't have to worry about `null`.

**Edit**

With your edited code I can see that the lines

```
if(face != null && suit != null && this.face.equals(s.face) && this.suit.equals(s.face))
        return true;
```

aren't quite right. Firstly you are comparing a `suit` and a `face` (obviously a typo). I'm also guessing that you want jokers to be equal? At the moment they won't be because if `suit == null` the method returns `false`. The lines should be simply

```
if (face == s.face && suit == s.suit)
    return true;
```

You do not need to use `.equals` for enum constants. The great thing about using `==` instead is that because you are not using a method, you do not need to worry about nulls.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my code with what you said. but my equals is not working for some reason, it returns false when the item does exist.

Comment: @mrnoobynoob Can you edit the question? Keep the original version there so that the 2 answers make sense, but add the new version underneath.

Comment: @mrnoobynoob No problem. I'm glad I could help.